# What does "plus funding in kind" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

In this [Newsweek](http://www.newsweek.com/uk-sugar-lobby-buttering-government-scientists-charge-preventing-obesity-306886) report, to says the following:

> The report claims that since 2004, Jebb has served as the sole or co-principal investigator on 10 research projects funded with £1.37 million ($2.1 million) in industry money, “plus funding in kind.”

What does "plus funding in kind" means in this paragraph? Is such funding included in $2.1 million or not? And why is it quoted in quotes?

Comment: It's probably quoted because it's a quote from the report.

Comment: Such such funding is definitely *not* included, since the cited text explicitly says ***plus** funding in kind*. Which by virtue of the preceding comma cannot possibly be parsed as part of a single total amount referred to as "industry money plus funding in kind" that totals £1.37M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [***in kind***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/in-kind) definition, sense 1:

> 1) in goods or produce instead of money

So it means he received some other goods or services that have some value but are not money (or can be sold/exchanged directly for money). Their value would be considered "funds" received for financial reporting purposes.

The quotes probably are because that was the wording in the report.